# What is gradle.properties.ftl file?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I installed Android Studio on Ubuntu recently and I want to alter `gradle.properties` file but I cannot find it. The only file is `gradle.properties.ftl`. I cannot understand the meaning of `ftl`. Should I change the name of `gradle.properties.ftl` to `gradle.properties`?

The content of `gradle.properties.ftl`

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
<#if isLowMemory!false>
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
<#else>
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
</#if>

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is a Freemarker template file from Android Studio. This file is used to create the real `gradle.properties` file, automatically by the IDE when you create a new Android project. Renaming it won't do any good as it is not a valid `.properties` file.

If you want to alter the properties, just create an empty `gradle.properties` file first.

Comment: Thanks. Should I put it alongside `gradle.properties.ftl` in the same directory?

Comment: How did you create the project? The properties file should be in the root of your project, along the `build.gradle`. The .ftl file is internal file of the IDE.

Comment: Also if you want global properties for all project, then put the properties in `$GRADLE_HOME` (on Ubuntu `~/.gradle` I believe)